# Enabling multi-line support for JSON file in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea, jackson

I'm using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) library to parse my JSON and map it to Java model class.
On top of that, I'm using 2 custom parsing options:

- `JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_COMMENTS`
- `JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_CONTROL_CHARS`

so my code looks like this:

```
public static void setClassProperties(Object target, String jsonObjectString) 
{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_COMMENTS, true);
    mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_CONTROL_CHARS, true);
    ...
```

However, after wast amount of time spent on googling I didn't find any way that I can enable these options in IntelliJ IDEA JSON editor - in the way so it doesn't show errors when I insert multi-line value:

```
{
      "Type": "CommandTask",
      "Description": "Run my script",
      "Executable": "Powershell",
      "Argument": "-file .\\MyScript.ps1
                            -Argument1 ${Argument1}
                            -Argument2 ${Argument2}
                            -Argument3 ${Argument3}"

},
```

Does anybody know how to enable Jackson JSON editor support for IntelliJ IDEA or at the very least to enable multi-line support?

Answer (score 1):

To get comments accepted, you can clear **Warn about comments** checkbox in  **Settings | Editor | Inspections, JSON | Compliance with JSON standard**. But there is no way to get rid of errors on multiline unquoted strings - this is the invalid syntax not accepted by JS/JSON parser

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to preserve JSON standard compliance and only allowing unquoted multi-line support for property values. It feels like there should be an ability to tweak JSON schema validator somehow...